# How do I add a light fixture to an existing 3 way circuit?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

Existing basement with 2 simple pull chain light fixtures. We want to add 1 more on the end of the room where the junction box for the circuit is. Can someone provide me a sketch?

Comment: What does the 3-way in the title have to do with it?

Comment: Sounds like you don't know much about this type of work, so it might be best to contact a local Electrician to complete the work.